# Perl one-liner is it possible to make END block execute for each file arg given

Tags: linux, perl

For Perl one-liners, when using the `-p` or `-n` flags is it possible to make the `END {}` block execute once per file, instead of only once for the entire program?

In other words, when I write:

```
perl -ne '$count++ if/.../; END {print "$ARGV: $count" if $count > 0}' mysourcedir/*.html
```

I'd like to execute the END block once for each file, instead of just once globally at the end of the program's execution.

Currently I just use xargs for this, but wondered if Perl maybe had some alternate flag for that behavior.

```
echo mysourcedir/*.html | xargs -n1 perl -ne '$count++ if/.../; END {print "$ARGV: $count" if $count > 0}'
```

PS - in case you're wondering why I don't just just `grep | wc -l` for this simple case, it's because this example is simplified from my real use case, which involves both incr (++) as well as decr (--) in the tally

---

Answer: Based on @mpapec's technique, plus a small tweak to also reset the $count var per file, I get this which works:

```
perl -ne '$count++ if/.../; if (eof && $count > 0) {print "$ARGV: $count"; $count = 0;} ' mysourcedir/*.html
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check `eof` for end of each file,

```
perl -ne '$count++ if/.../; eof && sub{ print "$ARGV: $count" if $count > 0 }->()' mysourcedir/*.html
```

or

```
perl -ne '$count++ if/.../; eof && do{ print "$ARGV: $count" if $count > 0 }' mysourcedir/*.html
```

Comment: @Vorsprung tnx, which part looks unusual to you?

Comment: I didn't think that the eof would "know" when it got to the end of each file.  I've always treated arg lists on -n or -p one liners as a single, big file.   Except when it's using -i as well of course.

Comment: @Vorsprung, yes `eof` does various things [depending on call format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't work like this (but see the answer of mpapec for an elegant alternative).

If I need to do this kind of thing I call Perl with `-e` only (no `-n` flag) and then do something like:

```
for my $filename (@ARGV) { open(my $file,"<$filename")||die$!; while(<$file>) {....
```

Then it is possible to take a count per file as the loop knows what file it is in.